# Temporarily storing array of invisible div elements

Tags: javascript, html, fusioncharts, dynamic-content

I'm working with FusionCharts, and the way that I'm using these charts is...

1. In javascript, a new chart is instantiated
2. New chart object creation requires specifying a div id
3. my page dynamically loads content from the server, while the user never actually leaves the page
4. The Fusion Charts doesn't allow creating a second chart within a div which already has a chart in it
5. With that being said, I need to pre-define each and every possible chart, even if its parent content page isn't loaded yet, and instantiate it upon page load.
6. Going further, in order to create those chart 'objects', I need to already have a div element designated for each particular chart, referenced by ID.

Here's a code snippet:

```
var Charts = new Array();
function InitCharts() {
    Charts[0] = new FusionCharts("MSColumn3DLineDY.swf", "divChartSSumA1", "340", "340");
    Charts[1] = new FusionCharts("MSColumn3DLineDY.swf", "divChartSSumA2", "340", "340");
    Charts[2] = new FusionCharts("MSColumn3DLineDY.swf", "divChartSSumA3", "340", "340");
}
```

Now the question with the above is how would I go about pre-creating the div elements and temporarily hiding them when not in use, then showing them inside their proper placeholder when they do need to be shown? I'd like the user to be able to quickly switch back and forth between the 'pages' of charts, each page being dynamically loaded from the server and 'injected' into the main content area of the page. Therefore, if the content for a particular chart isn't loaded, the chart object will raise errors that its parent div doesn't exist.

So specifically, how would I maintain an invisible list of named div's and show them in certain places as needed? The trouble begins with making sure each element perfectly corresponds with its chart object.

I'm also pondering the idea of what if I could create an invisible div object and store its reference in this array along with the chart? Better yet, how would I go about writing my own class which just has A) Chart Object, and B) div Element.

Just a note: When content section changes, and div's disappear, the chart placeholder div must be 'moved' back to its original place *before* the contents are cleared and replaced. I'm not sure what tricks there are to avoid this without moving innerHTML the hard way. I'm just worried about these div elements being *deleted* along with the page contents when it gets cleared (to be replaced with other dynamic page contents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a solution for this : "The Fusion Charts doesn't allow creating a second chart within a div which already has a chart in it", you already have solution:

Use insertMode constructor property in Object based constructor parameter. Possible values are "replace", "append", "prepend".

Example which tyou can try:

```
    var myChart = FusionCharts.render({
        swfUrl : "../../../../Charts/Column3D.swf",
        width: "400",
        height: '300',
        renderAt : "chartContainer",
        dataSource : '<chart caption="Weekly Sales Summary" xAxisName="Week" yAxisName="Sales" numberPrefix="$"><set label="Week 1" value="14400" /><set label="Week 2" value="19600" /><set label="Week 3" value="24000" /><set label="Week 4" value="15700" /></chart>',
        dataFormat : "xml"
    });


     var myChart2 = FusionCharts.render({
        swfUrl : "../../../../Charts/Column2D.swf",
        width: "400",
        height: '300',
        insertMode: 'append',
        renderAt : "chartContainer",
        dataSource : '<chart caption="Weekly Sales Summary" xAxisName="Week" yAxisName="Sales" numberPrefix="$"><set label="Week 1" value="14400" /><set label="Week 2" value="19600" /><set label="Week 3" value="24000" /><set label="Week 4" value="15700" /></chart>',
        dataFormat : "xml"
    });

     var myChart3 = FusionCharts.render({
        swfUrl : "../../../../Charts/Line.swf",
        width: "400",
        height: '300',
        insertMode: 'prepend',
        renderAt : "chartContainer",
        dataSource : '<chart caption="Weekly Sales Summary" xAxisName="Week" yAxisName="Sales" numberPrefix="$"><set label="Week 1" value="14400" /><set label="Week 2" value="19600" /><set label="Week 3" value="24000" /><set label="Week 4" value="15700" /></chart>',
        dataFormat : "xml"
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method you can adopt is to create a new div for every chart and hide/show them as required.

For example,

```
var Charts = new Array();
var openChart = null;
var chartTarget = $("#chartTarget");

for(var i = 0; i < nCharts; i++)
{
    var chartDiv = $("<div/>", {
        id:'chart_' + i
    });
    chartDiv.hide();
    chartDiv.appendTo(chartTarget);

    Charts[i] = new FusionCharts("Column.swf", "chart_" + i);

    // now the chart div has been hidden and appended to the target
}

function showChart(index)
{
    // first, see if an open chart exists
    if(openChart !== null)
    {
        openChart.hide();
    }

    // find the target chart div to show
    var targetChartDiv = $("#chart_" + index);
    targetChartDiv.show();

    // now the new opened chart is the target chart div
    openChart = targetChartDiv;
}
```

This way each of your charts rest in an unique id. And since the ID is defined by the index, you don't need to create an array of divs. Simply get the element by the ID and it should work fine..

Answer (score 1):

A cool way to solve your issue is to continue to instantiate the charts before page load as you are doing now. However, modify the constructor parameter to object-style notation. In object-style construction, you can pre-specify the id of the div where the chart will be rendered (using `renderAt` attribute) and then when page loads, simply iterate through the charts and call `.render()` on them.

Object-style notation provisions more parameters and configurations than the linear construction method that you are using now.

Example:

```
var charts = [];
function InitCharts() {
    charts[0] = new FusionCharts({
        swfUrl: "MSColumn3DLineDY.swf", 
        renderAt: "divChartSSumA1", 
        width: "340",
        height: "340"
    });
}

function onFinalLoad() {
    var i = charts.length;
    while (i--) {
        charts[i].render();
    }
}
```

Also, FusionCharts supports rendering multiple charts within a single div. In the object-style notation, simply provide `insertMode: "append"`

Refer [construction methods in JavaScript](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/?JavaScript/JS_CreateChart.html) in FusionCharts documentation to know more about object-style notation.